# java scalable email notification app

Tags: java, email, notifications, push-notification

I need to design and develop a Java application which sends email notifications to users on specific dates.
The information is stored in an Oracle 11g database. There is a table that contains records of notifications and each record have a 'due date'.
The 'due date' is simply a date (dd/mm/yyyy) of when that notification should be sent.

An email server will be available to use to send the emails.

The application will need to be scalable in the future as potentially it could be sending thousands of emails every day. The Application will also need
 to record if a notification failed to be sent so that it will retry sending it again later on.

The Java application will be hosted on Oracle Weblogic 10

what is the best way to go about designing or thinking about a solution to this problem?

I thought about using JMS but not sure if i am over engineering the problem (how do you deal with failed emailed?).

I can, of course, just write a simply Java app that will read the db table, get all notifications to be sent on that date, store them in an array, and just loop through and start sending each notification in an email. feeling that this way of developing the application is pretty primitive and not able to be scalable.
I guess the catch point is the fact that the solution should be able to handle sending of, potentially, thousands of emails a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to distribute the effort of sending a very large number of emails over several processes and/or threads, using a JMS queue would be one potentially effective way of coordinating the work.  It would spread the load evenly and it would also provide fault tolerance if multiple receivers were processing the work.

Some difficulties, however, might include the following:

- JMS Message reception is not, in general, guaranteed to be ordered.  Notifications intended for later times might be delivered before earlier ones.
- It might be difficult to maintain coordination between the database table and the queue.  Every insert/update/delete against the table might also require a message to be posted to the queue.
- It may not be desirable to post all future requests to the queue at once.
- A mechanism might be necessary to propagate cancelled requests through
  to the queue.

One possible solution:

Let an efficient, nimble front-end process read the table every so often and determine which notifications are due shortly.  Ideally, the database table would be indexed and/or partitioned to optimize this query.  Only these data are posted to the JMS queue.  The messages in the queue contain a reference to the database row.  The servicing process retrieves the database row before performing the notification, thus detecting changes/cancellations.

The Achilles heel in this approach is the front-end process.  Pains must be taken to ensure that it is always running and is, itself, fault-tolerant.  Also, the front end must have sufficient throughput to handle the entire load at any given moment in time.  If this is not possible, then multiple front-end processes might be required.  These could either take turns (say, odd minutes, even minutes, etc) or be coordinated, themselves, by another queue.

Comment: if you have 1 JMS queue. how many listeners/receivers would you suggest to create to handle a load of sending 10,000 emails a day?

Comment: Impossible to say in a vacuum, I think.  If the notifications are spread out evenly throughout the day, 10,000 is really not a lot.  I'd start with 2 listeners and take timings for how it scales as you ramp up the load.  The capabilities of your email server may also be a factor.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled almost trivially simple if you add an extra field "EMAIL_SENT" and let the email server handle the retries.  Note that it needs to be a production quality SMTP server like postfix or sendmail!

You then simply do a select with due_date < current date and EMAIL_SENT=false, and for each of the items in the result set send the mail (with a local client, not with a connect to port 25, this might be easiest with Linux), and set the EMAIL_SENT field to true.  Repeat again next minute.

You will most likely find that modern hardware easily can handle this load.

Comment: if the select query returned, say, 10,000 records/notifications to be sent in that day, then where would you store these 10,000 records as they are waiting to be processed? in an array list? is this efficient?

Comment: Just loop over the resultset. This will be faster than you think.